# Powershell output with names

Tags: powershell, shell-script

i have below this PowerShell command to get the output of the Ethernet Adapter speed on the computer name I specify:

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -ComputerName Computernamehere | Format-Table Name,@{label="LinkSpeed(MB)";Expression={$_.CurrentBandwidth/1000000 -as [int]}}
```

Now I have more than 60 computers and I have pasted the command over 60 times for the different 60 computer names in the same PowerShell script file each on one line and ended with an output text file by running From a command prompt

> powershell ".\LinkSpeed.ps1" > test.log

Can someone guide me to tweak the code so it would import the computer names from a text file and when I get the output it would come up with each computer name for its speed, cause I have to count on which line the wrong speed is and go back to the PowerShell script and look for that line to determine the name of the computer, below is the sample of the output.

> Name                                         LinkSpeed(MB)
>   ----                                          -------------
>
> Intel[R] 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection          1000
>
> isatap.domain.com                                         0
>
> isatap.{9B9559F2-1490-4661-81A2-6AA1DC382AF8}             0

Thank you.

Comment: `get-content` to get the computernames, loop over them with `foreach-object` and replace `computernamehere` with `$_`. Also, you can pipe the output to a file with `out-file -append` so you don't need `>`. This link explains basically what you need to do http://www.itninja.com/question/powershell-read-list-of-machines-from-txt-file-and-output-eventvwr-to-machinename-csv

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines is your best bet:

```
$output = $null

foreach($computer in (get-content c:\temp\60computers.txt)){

   $LinkSpeed = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface -ComputerName $computer

      foreach($link in $LinkSpeed){

      $object = New-Object psobject | Select ComputerName, LinkName, LinkSpeedMB
      $object.ComputerName = $computer
      $object.LinkName = $link.Name
      $object.LinkSpeedMB = [int]$Link.CurrentBandwidth/1000000

   [array]$output += $object
      }

}
$output | Out-File test.log
```

Breaking down what i have above we are step by step doing:

Looping Through all ComputerNames in the txt document called `60computers.txt`

Then `foreach` computer running the `Get-WMIObject` cmdlet to gather the information

Then creating a PowerShell Object to format the data how we want

Adding this to an array (quicker than appending to a file)

Then pushing the array to the log file.

Comment: the code looks good thanks, but unfortunately it gives me this error, Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface"
At C:\Users\712219\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:5 char:17

Comment: @Elie, I wasn't able to recreate that error on my machine unfortunately

Comment: maybe because we have different versions of windows, anyways thanks

Comment: Potentially the version of powershell also, It's about midnight local time for me but if i don't see this as an accepted answer in the morning ill try a few things at work tomorrow!